# Microsoft Teams Can't get group chat members

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a task module trying to post the **first** message to a new group chat in Microsoft Teams.
I'm getting the chat ID using the context and when I'm trying to resolve the chat members list using

```
GET /chats/{chat-id}/members
```

I get 404 error, I noticed that the chat id is a little different. it contains the word "preview" i.e "19:preview-xxxx" don't know if that's related

any suggestions?

Comment: we will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out.

Answer (score 1):

yes the chat id has a combination of numbers and characters,please use the complete chat id and it should work fine. My sample query that worked perfectly fine looked like this -
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/19:32*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1*x*.gbl.spaces/members.

Comment: What I said is, when I start a new group chat the ID is in this format "19:preview-xxxx...." and when I call the "getChatMembers" API it returns 404 error, I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Hi @Pahima7, Could please try once through graph explorer and check the results.

Comment: Tried multiple times,  
queried https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:preview-b935cc7d-9ede-44de-9eda-1a2ad533c251/members

got back 404

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue, could you please share us the repro steps.

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
1. create a group chat with several members.
2. Do not send a message to this group.
3. Get the group chat  chat-id using Teams-JS-API
4. call me/chat/{id}/members on the returned ID

expected: list of chat members
actual: 404 error code is returned.